# ¿Cómo crear una variable en thymeleaf y pasarla a spring?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Bueno mi problema es que no sé cómo declarar una variable en `thymeleaf` y que ésta me la reconozca spring con `@Pathvariable`. Dejo los métodos del HTML y del `controller`.

Éste es el `controller`:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/testing/{username}")
public String test2 (@PathVariable (value ="username") String user , Model model ) {
    model.addAttribute("titulo", user);     


    return "testing";
    
}
```

Éste, el HTML:

```
</div>`    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"
 class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" autofocus required th:whith ="username "/>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 1):

En realidad es muy sencillo. Solo necesitas agregar el dato que quieres a tu url. No tiene que ver tanto con Thymeleaf, lo puedes hacer con jquery o para fines de prueba directamente con el navegador.

Según el ejemplo que pones puedes usar como url lo siguiente:

```
localhost:8080/testing/rafaelRamirez
```

Puedes automatizarlo con jquery. Este es un ejemplo sencillo que utilizo:

```
$('.miBoton').click(function(event) {
        var a = $('.mi-input-que-coincide-con-la-info-que-quiero-mandar').value();

        var url = "localhost:8080/testing/"+a;
        //COMO TU CONTROLLER ESTA POR DEFECTO EN GET ESTO FUNCIONA CON
        //LA MISMA LÓGICA QUE LA URL DIRECTA EN EL NAVEGADOR.
        window.location.href = url;

    });
```

Y recibirás los datos en tu controller. Se puede mejorar para que te obtenga la variable actual y trabajes con la misma para todos los controller. Por ejemplo:

```
testing/eliminar/{id}
testing/modificar/{id}

otro-testing/eliminar/{usuario}
otro-testing/modificar/{usuario}
```

Igual funciona con POST y con GET, aunque con post puedes serializar el formulario (con thymeleaf generando la plantilla) y lo recibes directamente como un objeto más el dato de la url que le pases. Pero eso ya es otro tema.